# How to unzip 'gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT),' using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unzip

I am trying to unzip [this](https://github.com/mandarons/icloud-drive-docker/files/9138630/20210129_201905366.band.zip) archive file downloaded from iCloud.com using Python. None of the well-known methods work. I tried the following with Python 3:

1. using `shutil.unpack_archive()`
2. using Python's `gzip` library
3. using Python's `zipfile` library

When I inspected the file with Python's `magic` library and `xxd` tool, it shows following output:

`magic.from_file()` => `'gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), original size modulo 2^32 6670928'`

`xxd -l 4 ...` => `1f8b 0800`

What's so special about a zip file created on FAT? How to unpack it?

Comment: Okay, so exactly what problem are you encountering? "None of the well-known methods work" - what happened when you tried these methods, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen? "it shows following output" - okay, well, then? Do you think the output should be different? If you do, then what do you think the output should be instead, and why? If you don't have any particular expectation, then did you try to figure out what the output means?

Comment: In particular, where it says `gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem`, what do you suppose it means by `gzip`? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to find out, for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+a+gzip+file)? Did you try using a search engine [to figure out how to handle the file](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+open+gzip+file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question title suggests, it's not a zip file (despite the `.zip` filetype); it's a gzip file. Try using the `gzip` module:

```
import zipfile
FN = "20210129_201905366.band.zip"
print(f"{FN} is a zip file: {zipfile.is_zipfile(FN)}")

import gzip
GZ = gzip.GzipFile(FN)
contents = GZ.read()
print(f"{FN} is a gzip file with length: {len(contents)}")
with open('ungzipped.zip', 'wb') as i:
    i.write(contents)
import shutil
shutil.unpack_archive('ungzipped.zip')
# This produces correct output file - 20210129_201905366.band
```

prints:

```
20210129_201905366.band.zip is a zip file: False
20210129_201905366.band.zip is a gzip file with length: 6670928
```

It turned out to be a `zip` file (`20210129_201905366.band`) inside `gzip` file (`20210129_201905366.band.zip`).

Comment: Yeah, I can read the file using `gzip` but it is still in compressed format. e.g. if I dump `contents` from your code snippet into another file, it is same as the original file (still compressed).

Comment: Actually, they're not the same. I don't know why anyone is doing this but: 20210129_201905366.band.zip is a GZIP file, not a ZIP file. If you UNGZIP it you will get 20210129_201905366.band, which *is* a ZIP file.

Comment: you nailed it! Thanks for the pointer. To summarize, `20210129_201905366.band.zip` is a `gzip`, `20210129_201905366.band` is a `zip` and unzipping `20210129_201905366.band` using `shutil.unpack_archive()` worked. About your `why anyone is doing this...`, - that's Apple doing it for `package` files uploaded from iOS. Don't know why.

Comment: @Mandarons Okay, so. You say that you tried using the `gzip` library to open the file. When you did that, did you get the correct `20210129_201905366.band` result? If not, what was different between your code and the working code? If you did, then why did you conclude that this "didn't work"?